# Access Database to store and create different versions of a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create an Access database that can be used to store, create, and update slightly different versions of the same report. There are currently 190 *records* in one field containing what will be the body text (`long text` data type), and each of those fields will be stored in that table 11 times (one for each different version of the report). These all need to be that way because all of the fields will need to be updated at-will, and then reflected in the report.

The problem is this: I need each of the text fields to be formatted a certain way (bulleted lists, letter lists, headings, body paragraphs) based on criteria. My original thought was to specify and define those criteria in another table and then link it to the report table, but I'm not sure if that will work.

I currently have a query that pulls all of the text fields from one version of the report, but I can't figure out how to format correctly. How would I go about including lists/paragraphs/headings into a report?

Edit: Records, not fields

Comment: You need these 190 text fields *formatted a certain way*? Wow! This will require designing 190 separate, customized reports and map 11 rows of data through each accordingly!

Comment: I think you need to take a step back from your design and try again. 190 fields x 11 just to "Store it a different way" is a bad idea. Store it one way, format it in your report after your retrieve it according to how you want that report to look. What happened when you need 191 fields. You add 11 more fields to your table? And updating all of that data...

Comment: Oh my. I think I misspoke badly. I meant one field which will contain 190 * 11 records that will be different long text. Primary keys will be field number (1-190) and Form ID (1-11). Sorry! Post has been updated.